# How to "wrap" implementation in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, oop, class-design

I have these classes in C# (.NET Framework 3.5) described below:

```
public class Base
{
   public int State {get; set;}

   public virtual int Method1(){}
   public virtual string Method2(){}
   ...
   public virtual void Method10(){}
}


public class B: Base
{ 
  // some implementation
}

public class Proxy: Base
{
   private B _b;
   public Proxy(B b) { _b = b; }

   public override  int Method1()
   {
      if (State == Running)
         return _b.Method1();
      else 
         return base.Method1();

   }


   public override  string Method2()
   {
      if (State == Running)
         return _b.Method2();
      else 
         return base.Method2();

   }


    public override  void Method10()
   {
      if (State == Running)
         _b.Method10();
      else 
         base.Method10();
   }
}
```

**I want to get something this**:

```
public Base GetStateDependentImplementation()
{ 
   if (State == Running) // may be some other rule
     return _b;
   else 
     return base; // compile error
}
```

**and my Proxy's implementation will be**:

```
public class Proxy: Base
{
   ...
   public override  int Method1()
   {
      return GetStateDependentImplementation().Method1();
   }


    public override string Method2()
   {
      return GetStateDependentImplementation().Method2();
   }
   ...
}
```

Of course, I can do this (aggregation of base implementation):

```
 public RepeaterOfBase: Base // no any overrides, just inheritance
    { }

public class Proxy: Base
{
   private B _b;
   private RepeaterOfBase _Base;

    public Proxy(B b, RepeaterOfBase aBase) 
    { 
      _b = b; 
      _base = aBase; 
    }
}

...
     public Base GetStateDependentImplementation()
    { 
       if (State == Running)
         return _b;
       else 
         return _Base; 
    }
...
```

But instance of Base class is very huge and I have to avoid to have other additional copy in memory.

So I

- have to simplify my code
- have to "wrap" implementation
- have to avoid a *code* duplication
- have to avoid aggregation of any *additional
  instance of Base class* (duplication)

Is it possible to reach these goals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to extract the expensive state into its own class and share an instance of it between your concrete implementations.

Comment: Excellent (especially after I misunderstood your problem for so long) - good luck!

Comment: Really I have tried many variants. I need your last vote to be completely agreed. thanks. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can have your proxy object implicitly convert to Base like this:

```
public class BaseProxy
{
   private Base _base;
   private B _runningBase;

   public BaseProxy(B b)
   {
      _base = new Base();
      _runningBase = b; 
   }

   public static implicit operator Base(BaseProxy proxy)
   {
      return (State == Running) ? proxy._runningBase : proxy._base;
   }
}
```

This will allow your client code to get a reference to the underlying object (so it's not fully insulated), but it does allow you to access the proxy and have the methods behave as you expect.

---

Note: this doesn't actually allow the implicit usage like I thought.

Comment: But every time I need write ((Base)proxy).Method1().. :(
or should to add property to the proxy: 

public Base Implicit
        {
            get { return ((Base) this); }
        }

and should to call it:

proxy.Implicit.Method1();

Comment: You're right, I thought it would allow an implicit '.', but it doesn't.